# Android - How to create small Bitmaps from the one big Bitmap?

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I have the big Bitmap (720x6000) and I need to make 6 small Bitmaps (720x1000 each one) from it. How I can do that? Please, add some code to your answer.

Excuse me for my English, please.

Comment: You'd better scale that bitmap or you will run out of memory really quickly.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution whould be using static method `Bitmap.createBitmap (Bitmap source, int x, int y, int width, int height)` witch creates a new immutable bitmap(Immutable bitmaps cannot be modified. Trying to modify one will throw an exception) from the specified subset of the 'source' bitmap. If the smaller bitmaps have to be mutable you can convert an immutable bitmap returned by `Bitmap.createBitmap()` to a mutable one by calling `Bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config config, boolean isMutable)`.

```
Bitmap bigBitmap = ...;
Bitmap smallBitmap1 = Bitmap.createBitmap(bigBitmap, 0, 0, 720, 1000);
Bitmap smallBitmap2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(bigBitmap, 0, 1000, 720, 1000);
Bitmap smallBitmap3 = Bitmap.createBitmap(bigBitmap, 0, 2000, 720, 1000);
...
// to make small bitmaps mutable
smallBitmap1 = smallBitmap1.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
smallBitmap2 = smallBitmap2.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
...
```

Another solution would be creating empty small bitmaps and drawing portions of the big one on the smaller ones using a `Canvas`.